# How to convert a object to an object array? And sort by obj.value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input is an object like this:

```
let obj={
 a:1,
 b: 12,
 c: 2
}
```

convert to

```
arr = [{a:1},{c:2},{b:12}]
```

the values of this object is number.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Map over the key/val pairs then sort?

Comment: Your expected result is sorted by value, not by key, btw.

Comment: I'm sorry...sort by obj.value....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sort` and then `map` methods on `Object.entries`.

```js
let obj = {a: 1,b: 12,c: 2}

let arr = Object.entries(obj)
 .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
 .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
 
console.log(arr)
```